# Is it possible to hide Netbeans title bar like Firefox in Gnom 3?

Tags: gnome, 13.04, netbeans

I am using Ubuntu 13.047 with Gnome 3. I want to hide Netbeans(7.3.1) title bar like Firefox. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not. Netbeans, and all Java applications that use Swing toolkit draw their widgets on their own, without guidance from window manager (as is the case with Qt or GTK). So, you can not hide parts of the GUI, change fonts or colors, automate clicks and so on, unless the application directly supports it, which Netbeans, I think, do not. This is one of the reasons people dislike Swing.

Answer (score 0):

yes, but not natively, using some gnome extension for example: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1732/gtk-title-bar/

Comment: Additional information will help a lot more.

Comment: this is extension for gnome shell 'Remove title bars for non-GTK apps with minimal interference with the default workflow'